# how to populate asp:DropDownList from C# side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to populate asp:DropDownList with data items and here is the code i have written so far

.aspx side

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" />
```

C# side

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ddl.DataTextField = "hello";
  ddl.DataTextField = "2";
  ddl.DataBind();
}
```

The method `btnAdd_Click` is invoked. I tested it. But the data list is not getting populated with those data items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding your items like this

```
ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Your Text", "0"));
```

Comment: In ListItems each item got a text and a value representing that text so the zero would be the value in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `DataTextField` and `DataBind`, I asume you have a datasource to bind to your dropdownlist. If you want to do that you also have to have a `DataValueField`.

```
ddl.DataValueField = "id";
ddl.DataTextField = "name";
ddl.DataSource = GetData();
ddl.DataBind();
```

The `GetData` method have to return a datasource with an `id` and a `name` column.